# text does not render properly in java application

Tags: java, swing, jdeveloper, xfce

I am trying to run an old version of jdeveloper (10.1.3.2) with jdk 1.5.0_04 on ubuntu linux (15.04) running xfce4 desktop (4.12) and xfwm4 window manager.

this is how menus and text look like! selecting text or changing font-size sometimes helps.

[image: jdeveloper]

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: ubuntu 15.04  ..........

Comment: My thought process is that the error is being caused due to some compatibility issues between such an old version of an application and the OS you are running. I don't think the benefits of using jdeveloper 10.1.3.2 are worth trying to figure this problem out, honestly. Unfortunately I am no master at linux or operating systems in general, and I can't help you any further.